# animating a UIView up

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

```
    // Animate tag view up
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        _tagView.center = (CGPoint){_tagView.center.x, _tagView.center.y+40};
    }];
```

I'm trying to animate my _tagView up from where it currently is in IB, however the above code does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add more information for us to figure out what's wrong. Are you sure this code is even being executed? Is `_tagView` nil? etc.

Comment: the code is being executed, the _tagView is not nil nor hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want to move the view *up*, you need to decrease your `y` value (since origin is at upper left by default), like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
    _tagView.center = (CGPoint){_tagView.center.x, _tagView.center.y - 40};
}];
```

This code works just fine for me using a button to trigger the action. What are you triggering the movement with? Here's an Xcode (iPad) project that will move a view vertically up 40 pixels every button tap.

https://github.com/perlmunger/MoveUp.git

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to switch off the main view's "Use Autolayout" flag in Interface Builder. Auto Layout is enabled by default when you create a new project.

[image]

Comment: I assume then the initial position of _tagView is different than th expected endpoint..

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have added your tagView into the view hierarchy by calling `addSubview:`. Secondly, do your animation in `viewDidAppear:`; otherwise, use `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` if you are going to do it in your viewDidLoad.